# Opponent has a run in trump

Tags: pinochle

Can't find the answer to this anywhere, it happened to us last night. I got the bid and didn't make my run. BUT, the opposing team did get a run in Trump. Is their meld 150 points? Or just a marriage and dix?

Answer (score 3):

They get the full 150 for their run.

A run is by definition an A, 10, K, Q, J of trump suit; which is what they had. It is not required to be the person who won the bid in order to have a run.

From [the rules](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/pinochle-2/):

> The values of the melds are:
>
> > A,10, K, Q, J of trump suit (flush, or sequence) 150